# How to test which port MySQL is running on and whether it can be connected to?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL and even logged in there as a user.

But when I try to connect like this:

```
http://localhost:3306
mysql://localhost:3306
```

Neither works.  Not sure if both are supposed to work, but at least one of them should :)

How can I make sure that the port is indeed 3306?  Is there a linux command to see it somehow?
Also, is there a more correct way to try it via a url?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

To find a listener on a port, do this:

```
netstat -tln
```

You should see a line that looks like this if mysql is indeed listening on that port.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Port 3306 is MySql's default port.

To connect, you just have to use whatever client you require, such as the basic mysql client.

> mysql -h localhost -u user database

Or a url that is interpreted by your library code.

Comment: What does it mean when instead of 127.0.0.1:3306 it says 0.0.0.0:3306?

Comment: @mbmast the 127... means listen on local host only (not externally accessible). The 0.0.0.0 means "all interfaces", and therefore is (usually) externally visible.

Comment: I thought to be externally visible, it had to be the machine's own IP address and that 0.0.0.0 means the service is not available from anywhere.  Do I have that wrong? I have a box running MySQL, the firewall has 3306 open from any IP address but MySQL is refusing the connection, I thought because currently MySQL is listening on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Should merge this with @bortunac's answer, which references the `-p` parameter. Adding the process(es) really helps make this information more useful.

Comment: What does the -tln flag mean?

Comment: @JBeck three flags, for Linux. TCP, listeners, no name lookup. see `man netstat`.

Answer (score 163):

Using Mysql client:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.global_variables' doesn't exist

Comment: Much better if is used `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%port%';`

Answer (score 71):

`grep port /etc/mysql/my.cnf` ( at least in debian/ubuntu works )

or

```
netstat -tlpn | grep mysql
```

or

```
mysql -u user_name -puser_pass -e "SHOW variables LIKE 'port';"
```

verify

> bind-address 127.0.0.1

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to see possible restrictions

Answer (score 37):

```
netstat -tlpn
```

It will show the list something like below:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1393/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1859/master
tcp        0      0 123.189.192.64:7654     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2463/monit
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24135         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21450/memcached
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16781/mysqld
```

Use as root for all details. The `-t` option limits the output to TCP connections, `-l` for listening ports, `-p` lists the program name and `-n` shows the numeric version of the port instead of a named version.

In this way you can see the process name and the port.

Comment: Didn't work for me - I got "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - "

Answer (score 13):

Try only using `-e` (`--execute`) option:

```
$ mysql -u root -proot -e "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';"                                                                                                       (8s 26ms)
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
```

*Replace `root` by your "username" and "password"*

Comment: It's better to leave the password out of the CLI command: `mysql -u root -p -e "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';"`. It will prompt you to enter it, and it will prevent the password from showing in the `~/.bash_history` file.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler approach for some : If you just want to check if MySQL is on a certain port, you can use the following command in terminal. Tested on mac. 3306 is the default port.

`mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306`

If you successfully log in to the MySQL shell terminal, you're good! This is the output that I get on a successful login.

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9559
Server version: 5.6.21 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 8):

3306 is default port for mysql. Check it with:

```
netstat -nl|grep 3306
```

it should give this result:

**tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN**

Answer (score 7):

Both URLs are incorrect - should be

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/database
```

I thought it went without saying, but connecting to a database with Java requires a JDBC driver.  You'll need the [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Maybe you can connect using a socket over TCP/IP.  Check out the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

UPDATE:

I tried to telnet into MySQL (`telnet ip 3306`), but it doesn't work:

http://lists.mysql.com/win32/253

I think this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Did not seem to work when I tried it in my code :( Also when I pasted it into a browser, Firefox said it can't open such a thing.  Where/how could I try it out? - Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you can't open it in a browser.  You need the MySQL JDBC driver and Java code.

Comment: that's only if you are using Java.

Comment: I am trying to set it up using Ruby on Rails via the database.yml file.  But I just needed the port number really.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It's a six year old answer.  Where's yours?

Answer (score 6):

For me, @joseluisq's answer yielded:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But it worked this way:

```
$ mysql -u root@localhost  -e "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';"
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

On a mac os X, there are two options.  `netstat` or `lsof`

Using `netstat` will not show the process on Mac OS X.  so using netstat you can only search by port.
Using `lsof` will show the process name.

I did the following as I was encountering port conflicts (docker containers):

`netstat -aln | grep 3306`

Outputs:
`tcp46      0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN`

`sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "LISTEN" | grep -i 3306`

Outputs:
`mysqld    60608         _mysql   31u  IPv6 0x2ebc4b8d88d9ec6b      0t0    TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)`

Answer (score 4):

I think the most appropriate way of finding the port associated with mysql server using lsof command line tool.

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep mysql
mysqld    1556 prince   10u  IPv4 0x6ad3fd78a9051969      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a system where `netstat` is not available (e.g. RHEL 7 and more recent Debian releases) you can use `ss`, as below:

```
sudo ss -tlpn | grep mysql
```

And you'll get something like the following for output:

```
LISTEN     0      50        *:3306        *:*        users:(("mysqld",pid=5307,fd=14))
```

The fourth column is `Local Address:Port`. So in this case Mysql is listening on port 3306, the default.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bortunac's solution. my.conf is mysql specific while netstat will provide you with all the listening ports.

Perhaps use both, one to confirm which is port set for mysql and the other to check that the system is listening through that port.

My client uses CentOS 6.6 and I have found the my.conf file under /etc/, so I used:

`grep port /etc/my.conf` (CentOS 6.6)