# Phpstorm Database : java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm working on a website using JetBrains PHPStorm.
I created a database with default settings, when I try to test the connection or connect to the database, this error pops up :

> Connection to db_IHM failed 
>   java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:338)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:790)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>   at
>   com.intellij.persistence.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
>   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)   at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
>   at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:214)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.module.view.dataSource.LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:241)
>   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.module.view.dataSource.LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:217)
>   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:319)
>   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource.performJdbcOperation(DataSource.java:363)
>   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.AbstractDataSource.refreshMetaData(AbstractDataSource.java:32)
>   at
>   com.intellij.javaee.module.view.dataSource.DataSourceUiUtil$2.run(DataSourceUiUtil.java:177)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:420)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:150)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect   at
>   java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:297)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:790)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>   at
>   com.intellij.persistence.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: 1) Double (triple) check your login details (user name, password, host, port) 2) Firewall issue? 3) Maybe your login is not allowed to connect from this host -- check login permissions in your MySQL. **P.S.** I have seen 5 or 6 questions about MySQL connection problem in last 1 year or so -- in all cases it was misconfiguration from user and not an IDE issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue with PHPStorm on MAMP. Checked the port in localhost where MySQL was installed. It was 8889 and not the default 3306. Updating the port fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue, and I needed to enable "Allow network access to mysql" for it to work. [image: configuration settings on mamp pro]

Answer (score 2):

If you update your port number this issue will be fixed. So I thought it would be helpful if you know the step to find out the port number in which your mysql is installed.

In your mysql client type following sql query:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

OR use this stackoverflow link

[How to test which port MySQL is running on and whether it can be connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864242/how-to-test-which-port-mysql-is-running-on-and-whether-it-can-be-connected-to)