# PHPStorm doesn't connect to local MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, jdbc

I'm on OsX and trying to connect PHP Storm to MySQL.
While using MAMP it worked fine but now that I'm using directly MySQL, downloaded from the official website, PHPStorm doesn't connect to MySQL anymore.

PHPStorm returns this error:

> Connection to MyDatabase@localhost failed java.sql.SQLException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:338)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>     in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)   in
>   RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)     in
>   RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:229)    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.connect(Unknown Source)   in
>   LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:240) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:297)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>     in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)

I think it's something related to the configuration but I cannot understand which is the problem exactly.

PHPMyAdmin connects correctly simply using user and password, PHP Storm, instead, doesn't want to connect in any way.

Good tips to solve the issue? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334726/phpstorm-database-java-sql-sqlexception-communications-link-failure?rq=1

Comment: Also if that solution is for MAMP, it took me in the right direction: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the port on which MySQL were connecting.

To find the correct port number I used:

```
mysql > select user();
mysql > show variables;
```

This, among other things, showed me the port on which MySQL is connecting and that was 3307 instead of the default 3306, so the connection were refused.