# Connection refused to mysql database from C++ driver

Tags: c++, mysql, database-connection

### Problem

I'm following tutorial on Connect/C++ provided by dev.mysql. After copying the example and successfully compiling and linking it, I run into following issue:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
>
> what():  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

From what I know `111` stands for Permission Denied.

### Setup

Here is the example code taken from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html) and slightly modified:

```
#include <mysql_driver.h>

int main()
{
    auto driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    auto con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:0", "root", "123");

    delete con;
}
```

Trying with `tcp://127.0.0.1:3306` give the same result.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(mysql_try)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mysql_try ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(mysql_try PUBLIC /usr/local/include/mysql++)
target_link_libraries(mysql_try mysqlclient /usr/local/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a pthread dl)
```

I can easily run `mysql` with the credentials in the code. I disabled networking, so that it would only listen on `localhost`. Running

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

gave me 0, so I guess it is port 0.

C Connector and command line interfaces work just fine.

My OS is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Is the mysql server running?

Comment: @Galik, yes. As I mentioned, I can easily run `mysql` and perform queries.

Comment: Port `0`? Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @Galik, the query gave me that, so I guess it is correct. It is depicted in the ASCII art table that the query gave me. 0 is written to the right of `port`.

Comment: I would check your server configurtion to see what port mysql is running on. But if the commandline works it is probably the default one

Comment: @Galik, `netstat -tln -p` didn't give any `mysql` programs running. Also I don't know how to check installation, unfortunately. The default gives the same result

Comment: try to see in the service list if the mysql service is running and what are its parameters.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, the only thing I see is + to the left of mysql. I modified my.cnf to disallow networking, and thats it.

Comment: Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services. Select specific service - Right click - Properties. Check "Path to executable" value - it shows full path + parameters used to start the service

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, I believe ubuntu doesn't have control panel. Sorry for omitting the detail.

Comment: Have you tries all the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864242/how-to-test-which-port-mysql-is-running-on-and-whether-it-can-be-connected-to

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, `netstat -tln -p` doesn't have any 3306 in it, though I was able to run a C connector and a command line interface works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I disabled networking, so that it would only listen on localhost.

There's a difference between disabling networking all together (tcp) and specifying tcp to listen ONLY on your loopback adapter (127.0.0.1). Your mysql client is almost certainly connecting via Unix Socket, not TCP, which is why that works fine.  Verify that by running `mysql --protocol tcp`.  If that fails, then you know you disabled TCP connections all together, and it's connecting via Unix Socket.

> connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:0"

If you did disable networking with `skip-networking` you need to change your `connect()` to reference your socket file instead. See [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html)

> unix://path_name
>
> This URL format enables use of Unix domain socket files for connections to the local host on Unix and Unix-like systems. The path_name value is the socket file path name, just as for the --socket option of MySQL clients such as mysql and mysqladmin running on Unix (see Connecting to the MySQL Server).

Find your socket with:

> mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'socket'

If you want to keep your connect string the same, remove `skip-networking` and instead add
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

That should fix it!