# Cannot connect Mysql on another server

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, .net-core

I created a `DotNet` app that insert some data inside a database, for manage this situation and handle different database configuration, I've created a json called `cred.json` which contains all the information about the server connection. The structure is this:

```
{
  "Server":"localhost",
  "Database":"mydb",
  "User":"root",
  "Password":"root",
  "SslMode":false,
  "CharacterSet":"utf8",
  "Port":"3307"
}
```

the connection class contains a method called `Connect` that read the configuration available in `cred.json`:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cred>(File.ReadAllText("cred.json"));

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
 conn.Server = json.Server;
 conn.Database = json.Database;
 conn.UserID = json.User;
 conn.Password = json.Password;
 conn.SslMode = GetSslMode(json.SslMode);
 conn.CharacterSet = json.CharacterSet;
 conn.Port = json.Port;

MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(conn.ToString());
MySqlConnection.Open();
```

and I also have a method called `GetSslMode` that return the specific `SslMode`:

```
private MySqlSslMode GetSslMode(string sslMode)
{
    switch (sslMode)
    {
        case "Required":
            return MySqlSslMode.Required;
        case "VerifyCA":
            return MySqlSslMode.VerifyCA;
        case "VerifyFull":
            return MySqlSslMode.VerifyFull;
        default:
            return MySqlSslMode.None;
    }
}
```

the model `Cred` is a simple class which contains the structure of the json:

```
class Cred
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string SslMode { get; set; }
    public string CharacterSet { get; set; }
    public uint Port { get; set; }
}
```

when the code reaches `MySqlConnection.Open();` on Windows, it works, but when I try the app on Linux changing the port to `80` I get:

> connection must be valid and open

but the credentials are correct, how can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test which port MySQL is running on and whether it can be connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864242/608639) Also see [mysql port 3306 site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+port+3306+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default port for mysql is 3306 and I doubt that your mysql server is running on port 80 on Linux. It is probable that you access your webapp on that port on Linux environment (apache or nginx being used as well), or when you utilize its REST api.

If everything worked on your local environment but it fails to run when  you use it on a remote (Linux) server, it could be that you try to access same database from a remote server but you either use localhost in your config OR you happen to use the right ip/connection string but there are some permission issues. 
Another common mistake is disabled remote access to mysql database server (or for a given user), thus the potential need to setup i.e. ssh access, or to edit your mysql serlvler's configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using a Virtual Machine for test this. I changed the port as 3306 but same problem

Comment: Can you confirm whether you utilize localhost for your mysql server in your app settings/config and whether mysql server is also present on your virtual machine as well? Your current json utilizes port 3307, from what I see, and it also utilizes localhost. If you try to utilize this same database server, you'll need to change "localhost" to the appropriate IP, unless virtual machine has mysql server set up and running with the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your mysql daemon is not running as root, only root user can bind on ports below 1024. But it could be 10 other things. My advice is, run mysql on it's default port.